# Retrying POST request loses body c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I faced with the issue that after retrying the request my POST data got lost somehow.
Code sample below. (*Please note that request.timeout = 1 set for testing purposes to reproduce the behavior shown in the code below*):

```
//post_data_final getting

private void request_3()
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
        {
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post_data_final);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(site_URI);
            request.Method = "POST";
            //some headers info
            request.Timeout = 1;
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            using (Stream os = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                os.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }
            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                //some code about response
            }
            catch (WebException wex) 
            {
                if (wex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                //some additional checks
            }
        }
    }
```

The magic is that first request (until Request timeout error) goes well. Further requests are going **without** POST data, but content length is counted properly (i.e. stays the same as in previous request).

---

Updated:

1. post_data_final getting is separate function. It is not used (except byteArray) or changed in request_3() function.
2. Request works fine if it got into for loop and **Timeout exception has not occured**. So if I just put my request into for loop it will do particular number of **valid** requests. As soon as I'm getting Timeout exception, the next request will be without POST data.
3. Source code is edited for those who thinks that recursion is a bad idea. The edited code still doesn't work.

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Why do you use recursion the implement retries? That is going to break your neck...

Comment: Original code includes iteration counter for retries (i.e. after some unsuccessful requests it stops). It is cut to show the main issue.

Comment: I still think recursion is a bad idea. Write a new method called `request(int numOfRetry)` and call the `request()` method from inside a for loop, like `for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ if(request()) break; }` and your problems might have gone...

Comment: Tried the solution:
1) Put the request into for loop
2) Added `break` or `continue` into all nodes depending on logic. 
Results are the same =(

Comment: That does not make sense until some code changes the content of `post_data_final` to null or empty string. Show use the complete code, there must be something that has a side effect.

Comment: If it was so, then `request.ContentLength` should become `0`. But as I mentioned in the question it stays the same. So it really looks like magic to me.

Comment: The class member `post_data_final` is of what type?

Comment: `public string post_data_final;`

Comment: Have you verified that the form body is missing by looking at a network trace?  Maybe the error is on the receiving end instead...

Comment: Not on the receiving end, but in intercepting tool itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was because of using Fiddler2 - analogue of Wireshark (i.e. intercepting traffic tool).

Requested site uses https protocol. For debugging purposes I installed Fiddler2 and Fiddler2 certificate to be able to see all incoming and outcoming responses. For some magic reason when I turned off Fiddler2 and added some additional logging into console, i figured out that requests are appeared to be valid (i.e. POST body data still exists after first request).

So with Fiddler2 code above doesn't work while we're having Timeout exception. Without Fiddler2 everything works fine under the same circumstances and using the same code.

I didn't dig deep into Fiddler2, but seems to me issue could be only with compatibility of VS2010 and internal proxy for Error Codes (taking into account that using point 2 under "Updates" area (The Fiddler2 was also used there) for success codes (i.e. 2xx - 3xx) worked fine)

Thanks everyone for getting attention into this.

Answer (score 0):

I cant find anything wrong in your code, so provide mode details, as the comments mentioned.

```
private void request_3()
{
    bool sendData = true;
    int numberOfTimeOuts = 0;

    // The follwing only needs to be done only once, unless you alter post_data_final after each timeout.
    byte[] dataToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post_data_final);
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(site_URI);
    using (Stream outputStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        outputStream.Write(dataToSend, 0, dataToSend.Length);



    // request.TimeOut = 1000 * 15; would mean 15 Seconds.

    while(sendData && numberOfTimeOuts < MAX_NUMBER_OF_TIMEOUTS)
    {
         try
         {
             HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
             if(response != null)
                 processResponse(response);
             else
             {
                 //You should handle this case aswell.
             }

             sendData = false;
         }
         catch(WebException wex)
         {
             if (wex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
                 numberOfTimeOuts++;
             else
                 throw;
         }
    }
}
```